# Listing all exact Degrees, Minutes, Seconds for an entire area

Tags: qgis, data, latitude-longitude, degrees-minutes-seconds

Does a database or dataset exist that lists all exact Degrees, Minutes, and Seconds (rounded to nearest decimal) for the continent of South America? What I am seeking is a list of DMS's that covers that entire geography; not just a few specific coordinates, but all of them. Given that each DMS represents ~60 nautical miles apart, the data shouldn't be overly complicated to form. The trouble is, I can't locate the consolidated data anywhere on the web!

Answer (score 2):

Outline solution:

- Get boundary data for all countries in the region (can be downloaded from gadm.org)
- Loop over all D/M/S on the earth, doing point-in-polygon tests over the boundary data from step 1 - this can be done using Python, R, Java or C or lots of other programming languages.
- Keep those D/M/S values that are inside the boundaries.

How many points would you expect? The whole earth is 360 degrees round and 180 degrees north-south, so thats 360*60*60 * 180*60*60 = 8.4 x 10^11 points. South America is maybe 1/10 of the planet, so that's about 10^10 points - a few billion.

You'll end up with a table of a few billion points. I'm not sure how that would be useful, but that's how you'd do it.

Comment: I opted to use QGIS3 with the imported GADM.org boundary layer for the Earth. With the boundary layer correctly placed in the "layers" section of QGIS3, I then created a custom polygon shape. From there, I attempted to use the "Count Points in Polygon..." feature followed by the "Open Attribute Table" to collect the desired D/M/S values. Unfortunately, the resulting table indicates that there are zero points present within the polygon shape.

Comment: Did you first create a grid of DMS points over your study area?

Comment: I did not. The reason being is that I don't know the D/M/S points. The collection of the points was intended to come from the GADM.org data, or so I thought. How can I create a grid of points if the points are unknown at the time of capture?

Comment: In my outline you first generate a grid of DMS points over the whole earth. You can also generate a grid of points that span a vector layer in QGIS with one of the vector processing algorithms

Comment: Thank you for the further replies, Spacedman. I followed that outline (which was very much appreciated), but I'm still unclear on how to access the DMS points with which to generate the grid--the grid part I understand, as well as all points thereafter. How does one present/collect (for lack of a better word) the DMS points from the GADM.org data in the first place?

Comment: In QGIS, Vector...Research Tools... Regular Points will create a regular grid over a layer. You have to set the grid size to degrees, so to get a grid of arc-seconds you need to use 1/3600. But I don't think this will get points exactly on the DMS points, they could all be the same fraction of an arc-second away.

Comment: But all that said, I would have a think about what you are going to do with the 10 billion points over your study area.

Comment: Point well taken. An easier approach might be to select much smaller point-in-polygon areas, such as 900 square miles. Assuming one was to only allow D/M/S where the points were rounded to the nearest minute and second (for example 23° 32' 2'' S, 46° 37' 31'' W) that would rule out a large swath of complex point potential. Having said that, how would I create all DMS points rounded to the nearest minute or second that would actually plot onto the actual DMS points of the example 900 square mile area? Maybe it just can't be done?

Comment: Note that 1" is about 30 meters. It's possible to build a graticule (array of points or lines) in degrees. You can run into rounding issues because 1' = 0.016666... degrees and 1" = 0.000277777.... As @Spacedman asks, what do you want to do? Maybe a raster is better solution.

Comment: Thanks, @mkennedy. I'm not familiar with the raster approach, could you please briefly explain?